# How to save an R Corpus to disk

Tags: r, tm

I have a large R Corpus object, using the tm package, made up of millions of small documents.

How do I save that to disk as a single text file for use with other programs (such as word2vec)?

I tried

```
writeCorpus(myCorpus)
```

but that wrote out a million tiny text files that blew up my Mac!

I'm not very proficient in R, so any help on how to do this would be much, much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: do you plan on continuing to use the data in R or do you want to use it with other programs?

Comment: other programs - need it as a text dump for word2vec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
writeLines(as.character(mycorpus), con="mycorpus.txt")
```

But I don't know if it will be efficient with a million documents

Comment: perfect, thank you. Wrote out 55MB in under a second.