# Saving Corpus with meta info

Tags: r

Does anybody know if there is a out-of-the-box function to save VCorpus to disk along with its metadata? So far I m doing it with `write.table(...)` passing the dataframe with both texts and meta info to it. This is a little bit odd way imho since I first have to convert my VCorpus to data.frame and then write it as a table to disk which seems to be redundant step.

Maybe there is more efficient way to do it (save VCorpus to disk with meta)?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with text mining at all, but why don't you use `save` to save it as a usual R-object? then `load` it again when necessary with all metadata present. Or you want to work with it in another program (not R) ?

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020575/how-to-save-an-r-corpus-to-disk

Comment: Thank you, @inscaven, the thing is that with *save* I can then load saved R object only back in R. In my case I want to use it outside R.